# How can I cast a DataFrame column to integers (remove .0 at the end)?

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I have a ML model which takes two columns with types of String and bigint as an input.
The code below is the code to prepare an input data. The input data should be in a format like  {'data': [['12.5', 12]]} but after I covert the frame into Pandas and list, the data has .0 in the end.

How can I remove it?

```py
input_df = inference_df
test_df = input_df.select("avg_value", input_df.avg_value.alias("value"))
test_df = test_df.withColumn("avg_value", test_df.avg_value.cast("String"))
test_df = test_df.withColumn("value", f.round(test_df["value"], 0).cast("bigint"))
test_pddf = test_df.toPandas()
data = {"data": test_pddf.values.tolist()}

print(data)
```

result: `{'data': [['3341.650014545455', 3342.0], ['7020.98821', 7021.0], ['161.76136000000002', 162.0], ['160.047379', 160.0], ['11832.535650000002', 11833.0], ['4714.418000000001', 4714.0], ['5294.925936470588', 5295.0], ['9330.04428', 9330.0], [None, nan], ['1.5845243856846047', 2.0], ['29.144277718733324', 29.0], [None, nan]]}`

result I want: `{'data': [['3341.650014545455', 3342], ['7020.98821', 7021], ['161.76136000000002', 162], ['160.047379', 160], ['11832.535650000002', 11833], ['4714.418000000001', 4714], ['5294.925936470588', 5295], ['9330.04428', 9330], [None, nan], ['1.5845243856846047', 2], ['29.144277718733324', 29], [None, nan]]}`

Comment: Could you elaborate on what problem you're trying to solve by doing this? Why do you care about the presentation of the printed list?

Answer (score 1):

To cast a DataFrame column to `int`, you can use the [pandas method `.astype()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html), like so:

```py
test_pddf["value"] = test_pddf["value"].astype(int)
```

Edit: as [@Amadan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/240443/amadan) pointed out, there are `NaN` values in these data. To handle this, we need to leverage pandas' [nullable integer data type](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html), since Python's builtin `int` cannot accommodate `NaN` values. So, instead of casting to `int`, simply cast to pandas' version of integer, [`Int64`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Int64Dtype.html), which would make the `astype` call look like this: `test_pddf["value"].astype(pd.Int64Dtype())`. After doing this assignment, your `test_pddf` should look like this:

```
             avg_value  value
0    3341.650014545455   3342
1           7020.98821   7021
2   161.76136000000002    162
3           160.047379    160
4   11832.535650000002  11833
5    4714.418000000001   4714
6    5294.925936470588   5295
7           9330.04428   9330
8                 None   <NA>
9   1.5845243856846047      2
10  29.144277718733324     29
11                None   <NA>
```

Comment: You can't — there is a `NaN`.

Comment: @Amadan you can, you just have to tell it `errors="ignore"`. Thanks for pointing that out; I just added it to my answer.

Comment: Have you tried it? This results in a `numpy.float64` column again.

Answer (score 1):

Python has dynamic typing: a Python object can be of any type. Thus, a Python `list` can contain various types of objects.

A Pandas `Series` (which is how `DataFrame` represents columns) is backed by a `numpy.array`. `numpy` achieves the time and space savings that it does by representing all elements in the array with the same type. In your case, the `value` column is of type `float`  (or rather, `numpy.float64`) — which is why the numbers all look like `3342.0`. You can also have a `numpy.array` which contains `object` values, which can then hold values of any Python type, but then you don't get many of the benefits that `numpy` provides you.

A seemingly easy solution presents itself — why don't we cast the column as `int`? This would make the numbers look like `3342`, right? Well, no — because your values include `NaN`. The `int` type has no way to represent `NaN`. Even if your values started as integers, once you get `NaN`, `numpy` has no choice but to convert your column into floating point representation, where `NaN` is a valid value.

One way around it is to use the Pandas type [`Int64`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Int64Dtype.html) (a.k.a. `pandas.Int64Dtype()`) instead of `int`, which will convert `NaN` into `pandas.NA`:

```
df["value"].astype('Int64')
```

Comment: Just a nitpick, but `"Int64"` is *not* a.k.a. `numpy.int64`—it's a shortcut for `pd.Int64Dtype()`, which is a pandas *extension type* of NumPy's `int64` that enables nullability. If you try to cast a `NaN` to plain `np.int64`, you'll run into the same issue as with `int`

Comment: @L0tad Good point. I had even linked to `pandas.Int64Dtype` but still wrote what I wrote. Thank you!